# Succesive random numbers in a range

Tags: c++, random

I have this following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int getRandomNumber(int min,int max)
{
    static const double fraction = 1.0/(static_cast<double>(RAND_MAX)+1.0);
    return static_cast<int>(rand()*fraction*(max-min+1)+min);
}

int main()
{
    srand(static_cast<int>(time(0)));
    std::cout<<getRandomNumber(1,6);
    return 0;
}
```

If I run this program in succesions, then i get the same number. But when i run this one with cout statement as:

```
std::cout<<getRandomNumber(1,6)<<getRandomNumber(1,6);
```

I get different numbers every time. 
So how is this possible?? Am I missing something?

Comment: I run the above program with two cout. It gives the two same number as result.

Comment: I see you using an int number. It can be generated using rand() only. Why you going through much trouble. 'cout<<rand()<<" "<<rand();'

Comment: By the way; getRandomNumber() can generate at most RAND_MAX+1 different numbers, regardless of min and max. And it is relatively easy to predict the numbers that cannot be returned.

Answer (score 2):

The `time()` function returns time in *seconds* so running the program two or more times within the same second will cause the random number system to be seeded with exactly the same number.

Comment: time() function is used in first srand function; is never used , hence have no relation with what we see as output.

Comment: @denis on the contrary. The `time()` function is used in the call to `srand()` and it determines the sequence of random numbers that will be produced by the `rand()` function. If you call `srand()` with the same number you get exactly the same sequence of random numbers from the `rand()` function.

Comment: Guys, I am using Codeblocks. Whenever i use single call to getRandomNumber(), i get same number,like 5. But when i call it two times, it generates two random number even during the same second every time i run,like 56 or 42.

Comment: @Hope It is calling `srand()` two times in the same second that causes the problem. You can call `rand()` as many times as you want it will give you random numbers **unless** you keep resetting it using `srand()` more than once per second.

Answer (score 0):

When using function time() as seed and running program within short interval, the first result of rand() will be changed in a very small number comparing to RAND_MAX.

This explained why you got the same number, when using fraction to get a number from 1 - 6.

Here is another way to get random number from 1 to 6, which may do better.

```
rand() % 6 + 1
```